# How to type in between two bracets-Batch File

Tags: variables, batch-file, windows-xp, ip-address, user-input

Hey well I'm here again and this time I want to know how to type in between bracets from an input variable for the input of an IP Address.

I want the code to look something like this.

```
set input=
set /p input=IP Address: [     ].[     ].[     ].[     ]
```

And once I've executed the batch and typed in my IP I want it to look like this.

```
IP Address: [ 127 ].[ 0 ].[ 0 ].[ 1 ]
```

Is there anyway of doing this?

Comment: You need third party programs to realize this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be a very complicated thing to do.

If you would try to do this in Batch you need to rewrite your line with braces on every keyboardhit the user does. The only command I know so far which listens on a single KB-hit is the Choice command.
If you manage it somehow to repeat the users input on every KB-hit you need to bytehack your batch file with backspace characters and have a logic to combine the users input with the braces. This is not only very unconfortable but also very slow.

I would recommend to let your users enter any string and after this checking it by "regex" (windows regex is not very nice)

Here is an example function which I use to check IPs of printers.

%printer% would be the string your user enters. This functions also has an nslookup function. You can ommit this if you like.
This 2nd line does all the magic, but you can also enter some IPs which are not possible like 321.099.000.666

```
:CheckIP
echo %printer% | findstr /R "[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*">nul || goto :EOF
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A in ('nslookup %printer% 2^>^&1 ') do (
    echo %%A | findstr /R /C:"Name: ">nul && set printer=%%A
    echo %%A | findstr /R /C:"\*\*\*">nul && (set printerfqdn=%printer% & goto printerip)
)
rem ***************************************
rem * Name:    printername.location.companydomain
rem * printerfqdn begins at position 10
rem ***************************************
set printer=%printer:~9%
goto :EOF
```